# Blob downloadToFile() not downloading large files Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

I have implemented ** azure blob/storage** in my project. And it works fine on smaller files but when I try to download a file more than 40 MB. it does not return from  blob.downlaodToFile()
Here is my code.
**Api call**

```
exports.downloadSingle = function(req,res){
  downloadService.downloadSingleFile(req.params.id).then(function (result) {
    res.send(result);
  })
}
```

**Downlaod service**

```
    var filesLocalLinks = [];
    const request = require('request-promise');
    const fs = require('fs');
    var download = require('download-file')
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      filemodel.findOne({_id: id,cancelled: false}).exec(function(error,result){
        if(error){
          resolve(error);
        }else{
          
              blobDownload.downloadFile(result.blobName,result.containerName).then(function(blobResponse){
                var filename = path.resolve(__dirname+'/../services/uploads/'+result.fileName);
                   filename = filename.replace('/myProject','');
                   filename = process.env.BASE_URL+'/myProject/services'+filename.split('/services')[1];
                   resolve({file: filename, filename: result.originalname})
              }).catch(function(error){
                reject(error);
              })
        }
      })

    })
    let result =await promise;
    return {file: result.file,filename: result.filename };
  }
```

**Blob service**

```
    let promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const account = process.env.BLOB_ACCOUNT;
    const accountKey = process.env.BLOB_ACCOUNT_KEY;
    const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      sharedKeyCredential
    );
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
    var blobResponse = await blobClient.downloadToFile(blobName);
    resolve(blobResponse)
    })
    let result =await promise;
    return result;

  }
```

**In blob service, this line take too much time that the page responds page not working something** `var blobResponse = await blobClient.downloadToFile(blobName);`
Can anyone help me

Comment: You can use the method  `download` to read blob content in a stream :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#download-number--number--blobdownloadoptions-

Comment: I have figured it out, It was memory issue

Comment: Since the issue has been resolved, could you post your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the flow of code is, first it download the file to our server directory and then the user can download it. I figured it out that the code was working fine, but the issue was of the memory of our server, as we increased the memory, the issue is resolved. But it took my 2 days to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I came across that out of the blue.. but I noticed that you put `blobName` as a parameter of  `downloadToFile` call, instead of the target file's name, not to mention that the line  `const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);` seems to be unnecessary, which suggests that you didn't look into your own code properly...