# download file from azure blob nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, blob

I have implemented file downloading from blob like this [Blob downloadToFile() not downloading large files Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63735185/blob-downloadtofile-not-downloading-large-files-nodejs) . and is working fine. But the problems is the flow of download which is **azure -> our server ->user** but the flow I want is **azure->user**. Please have a look at the link, up there and help me to change the flow of downloading.

Comment: If the file wants to be downloaded to the local, the web application must be the browser to request the file url and perform the operation.

Comment: I am just testing it. if this will work I will definitely mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7687666/jason-pan what if I use file stream something to frontend and let them handle the stream and then download it>

Comment: Can you share me a test api which need contain`Content-Disposition`,`attachment;filename=filename.format`,`Content-Length`. I will try it later.

Comment: `const blobService = storage.createBlobService(process.env.BLOB_ACCOUNT, process.env.BLOB_ACCOUNT_KEY); // if you want aren't using the same azure env vars

      blobService.getBlobToStream(result.containerName, result.blobName, res, function (error, blob) {
        if (!error) { // blob retrieved
          console.log(blob); // good for debugging and possibly more processing
          res.end() // no need to writeHead
        } else {
          console.log(error);
          res.end();
        }
      });`

Comment: I have done it using this getBlobToStream() but now the other problem is to convert this file to zip. Can you help with that

Comment: I have updated my answer,  pls check it.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: no luck with what i am trying to do

Comment: Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: Can you provide your sample code? Be careful to hide confidential information.

Comment: In theory, according to my current code, the server returns the stream, and the front-end js processing is no problem, as you can see from the animated gif.

Comment: I have changed your code because it wasn't converting it to zip.then I have tried another code but that code converts file(image) to zip but when extracting the zip half image is displayed and half is blur. can I send you that code?

Comment: this code is perfect for download single file.

Comment: Sorry dude I was confused with another question. I thought this question is about downloading zip. this single stream code is perfectly working.

Comment: If possible, you can upload your code to github (be careful to hide confidential information), and repost a post. When the post problem is solved, you can choose to delete the code on github.

Comment: Because there are many ways to implement a function, so is the code, and many frameworks can be used. Sometimes specific problems require specific analysis. Be sure to double check that confidential information has been protected.

Comment: ok i will be uploading it in some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

My latest updated answer describes the processing of the file stream sent from the back-end to the front-end processing. Please google yourself to convert files into streams. Let me answer the question you asked last time.

**First, please see the renderings:**

[image]

**Server Code:**

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const fs = require('fs');
const path =require('path');
const mineType = require('mime-types')

app.listen(7001,()=>console.log('server start'));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    let filePath = path.resolve('mygif.gif');  // local file in project
    let data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    let bufferData = new Buffer(data,'base64'); 
    let base64 = 'data:' + mineType.lookup(filePath) + ';base64,' + data; 
    res.send(base64)
})

app.get('/filedownload',function(req, res, next){
    //solve cros issue
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH");
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age',1728000);
    // file info 
    var currDir = path.join(__dirname,req.query.dir),
        fileName = req.query.name,
        currFile = path.join(currDir,fileName),
        stats = fs.statSync(currFile);
    fs.exists(currFile,function(exist) {
        if(exist){
            res.set({
                "Content-type":"application/octet-stream",
                "Content-Disposition":"attachment;filename="+encodeURI(fileName),
                'Content-Length': stats.size
            });
            let fReadStream = fs.createReadStream(currFile);
            fReadStream.pipe(res);
        }else{
            res.set("Content-type","text/html");
            res.send("file not exist!");
            res.end();
        }
    });
});
```

**Html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function aa(){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
            xhr.open("get", 'http://localhost:7001/filedownload?dir=&name=mygif.gif', true);
            xhr.responseType = "blob";
            xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                var blob = this.response;
                console.log(blob);
            }};
            xhr.send();
        }
        function bb(){
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("GET", "http://localhost:7001/filedownload?dir=&name=mygif.gif", true);
            oReq.responseType = "blob";
            oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
            var content = oReq.response;

            var elink = document.createElement('a');
            elink.download = 'mygif.gif';
            elink.style.display = 'none';

            var blob = new Blob([content]);
            elink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            document.body.appendChild(elink);
            elink.click();

            document.body.removeChild(elink);
        };
        oReq.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="aa()">convert file stream</button>
    <button onclick="bb()">download</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**PRIVIOUS**

The download behavior must be the browser's response. No matter how coded your node backend code is, it will be downloaded to the server.

To download to the browser client, the easiest way is to execute `window.open(downloadurl)`.

The most friendly way is to generate a backend to return something similar to `<a href="data:text/plain,this is some text" download="some-filename.txt" target="_blank">Download<a>` The message prompts the user to download.

Note that if the file is too large, it will slow down the download speed, please refer to my answer in another post.

[**Improve axios get download speed**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336999/improve-axios-get-download-speed/63482849#63482849)